# how to pass an argument as a variable name in R

Tags: r, arguments

I need help with passing an argument as a variable name in an R script from the terminal. I'll run the script as follows:

```
R < script.R --args "hello"
```

And, in the script there should be something like this:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
assign(args[1],24)
save(args[1], file="output.RData")
```

But, I need to take the argument as the variable name. What I mean is the following: If I run the script with "numbers" argument, the variable name inside the script should be numbers.

```
assign(args[1], 24)
```

does the trick. But, inside the save function, args[1] does not work. How can I pass it as a variable name?

Comment: I could not manage to work this out using save. However, since all I want is to save one object (a list), something like this works: saveRDS(thevariable,file=paste0(args[3],".rds")).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you try

```
saveRDS(get(args[1]),file="output.rds")
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a text file with the `save` function. If you want its text version you would need to use `dump". This would "work" despirte the extention. The file ois still an .Rdata file event without the extension:

```
arg=1
argname="reports"
assign(argname, arg)
reports
#[1] 1
save(reports, file="test.txt")
rm(reports)
rm(argname)
rm(arg)
load("test.txt")
```

To use dump:

```
 dump('reports', file="test2.txt")
```

This would appear in that file. It should be parse-able (and readable to humans) R code:

```
reports <-
1
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I need .RData file, not a .txt file as the output.

Comment: I don't how that makes a substantial difference.